# Value from a dropdown list isn't passing to the next page when I do a query string parameter

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to use the DataTextField property of a dropdown list to finish the link to the page it is supposed to navigate to. Here's the code:

page1.aspx

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Search by last name: <asp:TextBox ID="searchTB" runat="server"/><br />
        Search by first name: <asp:TextBox ID="FNameTB" runat="server"/><br />
        </td>
        <td style="padding-left: 10px;">
            Search by Organization: <asp:DropDownList ID="OrgDDL" runat="server" 
                DataSourceID="AccessDataSource2" DataTextField="SectionName" 
                DataValueField="ID">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource2" runat="server" 
                DataFile="~/App_Data/webvideos.mdb" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ORG_SECTIONS]">
            </asp:AccessDataSource>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center;"><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="Search" /></td>
        <td style="padding-left: 10px; text-align: center;"><asp:Button ID="SearchbyOrgBtn" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="SearchByOrg" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Search(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //TextBox LastName = (TextBox)this.FindControl("searchTB");
    Response.Redirect("OrgsByName.aspx?LASTNAME=" + searchTB.Text);
}
protected void SearchByOrg(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //TextBox LastName = (TextBox)this.FindControl("searchTB");
    Response.Redirect("NamesByOrg.aspx?SectionName=" + OrgDDL.DataTextField);
}
```

NamesByOrg.aspx:

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/App_Data/webvideos.mdb" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT ORGANIZATIONS.ORG_NAME, ORG_SECTIONS.SectionName, ATTORNEYS.NAME, ATTORNEYS.LASTNAME, ATTORNEYS.EMAIL, ATTORNEYS.TEL
         FROM (ORGANIZATIONS INNER JOIN (Org_Sec_Atty INNER JOIN ATTORNEYS ON Org_Sec_Atty.Atty_ID = ATTORNEYS.ATTY_ID) ON ORGANIZATIONS.ID = Org_Sec_Atty.OrgID) INNER JOIN ORG_SECTIONS ON Org_Sec_Atty.SecID = ORG_SECTIONS.ID
         WHERE ORG_SECTIONS.SectionName LIKE @SectionName;">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="SectionName" QueryStringField="SectionName" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource>
```

It doesn't matter what value I select in the DDL, it always tries to navigate to "NamesByOrg.aspx?SectionName=SectionName". When I had it as a textbox, it worked fine, but I'd like to keep it as a DDL for obvious reasons, lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `DataTextField` is defined in the `.aspx` that you've provided, which happens to be `"SectionName"`.

What you're looking for is something like `SelectedValue` or `SelectedItem` which will return whatever you selected in the drop down.

Comment: See, I knew it was stupid. Thanks. I can accept your answer in 8 minutes.